# Window resizing

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a window skin with gripper. 
Gripper is use to resize window with to listener mousedown and mouseup.

My problem is when i finish to resize window, I stop to press mouse and if I click anywhere on window, the window is resizing and I don't know why.

The below part of my code:

```
protected function btResize_mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, btResize_mouseUpHandler );
            stage.nativeWindow.startResize();
        }

        protected function btResize_mouseOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, btResize_mouseOutHandler );                
        }


        protected function btResize_mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, btResize_mouseUpHandler );



        }

<s:Button height="15" id="btResize" width="15"
          bottom="0" right="0"
          skinClass="spark.skins.spark.windowChrome.GripperSkin" 
          mouseDown="btResize_mouseDownHandler(event)"
          mouseUp="btResize_mouseUpHandler(event)"
          buttonMode="true"/>
```

So, I appreciate, your help.

Thanks

Ps : Entire code

```
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
         xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009"
         xmlns:Layout="skin.Layout.*"
         alpha.disabledGroup="0.5"
         creationComplete="sparkskin1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">

<fx:Metadata>
    [HostComponent("fr.inter.ui.windowSkin.wCustomWindow")]
</fx:Metadata>


<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        protected function btResize_mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            btResize.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, btResize_mouseUpHandler );
            stage.nativeWindow.startResize();
        }

        protected function btResize_mouseOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            btResize.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, btResize_mouseOutHandler );             
        }


        protected function btResize_mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            btResize.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, btResize_mouseUpHandler );



        }

        protected function sparkskin1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {

            if (NativeApplication.supportsDockIcon)
            {
                this.currentState = "supportsDockIcon";//mac
            }
            else
            {
                this.currentState = "supportsSystemTray";
            }
        }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<s:states>
    <s:State name="disabledAndInactive" stateGroups="disabledGroup, inactiveGroup" />
    <s:State name="maximizedGroup"/>
    <s:State name="normal" />
    <s:State name="disabled" stateGroups="disabledGroup" />
    <s:State name="normalAndInactive" stateGroups="inactiveGroup" />
    <s:State name="supportsDockIcon" />
    <s:State name="supportsSystemTray"/>
</s:states>

<s:Rect id="backgroundRect"
        left="0"
        right="0"
        top="0"
        bottom="0"
        alpha="0"
        >
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor alpha="0"/>
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>

<s:Group bottom="0" left="0" right="0"
         top="0"  
         >
    <!--Fond de la fenetre-->
    <s:Rect bottom="0" left="0" right="0"
            top="0"
            radiusX="8" radiusY="8" >
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="#656565" alpha=".7" />
        </s:fill>
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="#666666" />
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <s:Group height="38" id="moveArea"
             left="0" right="0" >

        <!--Barre bleu avec filet-->
        <s:Rect  height="25" left="10" right="10" top="10">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="#055a90" />
            </s:fill>
            <s:stroke>
                <s:SolidColorStroke color="#666666" />
            </s:stroke>
        </s:Rect>


        <s:BitmapImage id="icon"
                       left.supportsSystemTray="5" right.supportsDockIcon="5"
                       verticalCenter="0" />

        <s:Label id="titleDisplay"
                 styleName="swindowTitle"
                 left.supportsSystemTray="60" left.supportsDockIcon="{this.width/2}"
                 top="18" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalCenter="0"
                 />

        <!--Zone de bouton-->

        <s:HGroup right.supportsSystemTray="12" left.supportsDockIcon="12" verticalCenter="0">

            <s:Button id="btMinimize" buttonMode="true" 
                      skinClass.supportsSystemTray="skin.components.MinimizeButtonSkin"
                      skinClass.supportsDockIcon="skin.components.MinimizeButtonSkinM"
                      verticalCenter="0"/>

            <s:Button id="btMaximize" buttonMode="true" 
                      skinClass.supportsSystemTray="skin.components.MaximizeButtonSkin"
                      skinClass.supportsDockIcon="skin.components.MaximizeButtonSkinM"
                      verticalCenter="0"/>

            <s:Button id="closeButton" buttonMode="true" 
                      skinClass.supportsSystemTray="skin.components.CloseButtonSkin"
                      skinClass.supportsDockIcon="skin.components.CloseButtonSkinM"
                      verticalCenter="0"/>

        </s:HGroup>

    </s:Group>

    <!--Fond de la zone principale-->

    <s:Rect id="background" left="10" top="35" right="10" bottom="10">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="-90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="#edf0f7"/>
                <s:GradientEntry color="#fcfbfb" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="#666666" />
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <!--Zone dans laquelle les elements vont se positionner-->


    <s:Group id="contentGroup" left="15" right="15" top="43" bottom="15" minWidth="0"
             minHeight="0" width="100%" height="100%">

    </s:Group>



</s:Group>
<s:Button height="15" id="btResize" width="15"
          bottom="0" right="0"
          skinClass="spark.skins.spark.windowChrome.GripperSkin" 
          mouseDown="btResize_mouseDownHandler(event)"
          buttonMode="true"/>
```

Comment: Does this also occur if you remove your mouseUp handler?  According to the docs it looks like it should stop the resizing sequence as soon as it gets a mouseUp event, I'm wondering if your registering and unregistering of the mouseUp listener is causing some sort of problem.  Based on reading here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html#startResize()

Comment: the problem always exit even if I remove mouseup hadler.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior does not occur for me.  I'm using flex SDK 4.6 targeting AIR 3.1. So one option (if possible) is to upgrade your SDK if it is not at 4.6.

The code below works as well.  Notice I changed `stage` to `this`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.ResizeEvent;
            protected function btResize_mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                this.nativeWindow.startResize();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Button height="15" id="btResize" width="15"
              bottom="0" right="0"
              skinClass="spark.skins.spark.windowChrome.GripperSkin" 
              mouseDown="btResize_mouseDownHandler(event)"
              buttonMode="true"/>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: In my case this.nativeWindow is unknown, I must pass stage.nativeWindow. And I work with Flex 4.5. So I try update to 4.6 . Thanks

Comment: What is your parent class? Can you post your entire MXML file?